# Convert '[Publishers.Map<URLSession.DataTaskPublisher, [ProductRep]?>]' to [ProductRep]

Tags: swift, functional-programming, combine

How do I figure out the flatMap, reduce, etc. to turn this into an array of ProductRep?

I'm currently getting `Cannot convert value of type 'Publishers.Map<URLSession.DataTaskPublisher, [StoreService.ProductRep]?>' to closure result type 'StoreService.ProductRep'` - because I don't really understand how to turn a `Publishers.Map` into the actual thing. 
This is intended to be part of a larger network of publishers and subscribers using map/flatMap.

```
let mapResult: [ProductRep] = parsePageURIs(firstPage, jsonDict)
            .map { pageUri in self.importProductsPublisher(pageUri, urlSession: urlSession, firstPage: false) }
            .map { publisher in publisher.map {(productsData, productsResponse) in
                    return self.handleImportProductsResponse(data: productsData, response: productsResponse, category: category, urlSession: urlSession)
                }
        }
func importProductsPublisher(_ uri: String, urlSession: URLSession, firstPage: Bool) -> URLSession.DataTaskPublisher { /* Start the network query */ }
func handleImportProductsResponse(data: Data, response: URLResponse, category: CategoryRep, urlSession: URLSession) -> [ProductRep]? { /* Handle the result of the network query and parse into an array of items (ProductRep) */ }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's 2 things going on here. Firstly, you are missing a sink of some kind, usually you'll see a chain of publishers end in something like .sink or .assign

```
whatever.map{ ... }.sink{ items in 
//Do something with items in this closure
}
```

Secondly is you appear to be mapping page uris to a collection of Publishers, rather than a single publisher. Then you have a nested map inside a map, which doesn't resolve anything yet.

You may be able to use one of the merge publishers, like merge many and collect to reduce from one publisher to many:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/mergemany/3209693-collect

A basic collection example:

```
let arrayOfPublishers = (0...10).map{ int in
    return Just(int)
}

Publishers.MergeMany(arrayOfPublishers).collect().sink { allTheInts in
    //allTheInts is of type [Int]
    print(allTheInts)
}
```

I *think* you need something like this:

```
 let productPublishers = parsePageURIs(firstPage, jsonDict).map { pageUri in
    return self.importProductsPublisher(pageUri, urlSession: urlSession, firstPage: false).map {(productsData, productsResponse) in
        return self.handleImportProductsResponse(data: productsData, response: productsResponse, category: category, urlSession: urlSession)
    }
 }

 Publishers.MergeMany(productPublishers).collect().sink { products in
   //Do somethings with the array of products
 }
```

map the uris to publisher results in a Model after mapping a data request publisher, then merge all your publishers to take the individual results into one array with MergeMany & collect, and finally the sink which actually triggers everything to happen.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I hadn't really realized there were basically only two subscribers - I'm too used to the Scala-style Future interface. The MergeMany kind of works. It does merge the streams but it propagates the Finished message. This means that the sink completes just on the first stream to finish. I'll work on something suitable to deal with that...

Comment: When I was testing I found that if I left out the call to `collect()`, it'd trigger the sink for each of the publishers, in case that helps.

Yeah, you can make custom subscribers I believe, but I haven't gotten that far or felt the need to yet. Still early days.